# Como pasar un array bidimensional de php a js

Tags: php, javascript, array

Tengo un array en php con la siguiente estructura

```
$arrayPeticiones['2020-01-15']['comida'] = 2;
$arrayPeticiones['2020-01-15']['cena'] = 1;
```

Donde el indice del array sea la fecha para luego compararla con la fecha que quiero. Pero he intentado pararlo de la siguiente forma pero me da un error.

```
var arrayFechas= "<?php echo json_encode($arrayPeticiones) ?>";
```

Pero me da un error de unexpected number 
y me devuelve lo siguente arrayFechas

```
{"2019-12-25":{"comida":0,"cena":0}}
```

Alomejor asi queda más claro como creo el array

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<count($dias) ; $i++){
      $dias[$i];
      $comidas = $this->Eventos->find()->where(['start' => $dias[$i], 'centro_id' =>$usuario['centro_id'], 'tipo_comida_id' =>'1'])->count();
      $cenas = $this->Eventos->find()->where(['start' => $dias[$i], 'centro_id' => $usuario['centro_id'], 'tipo_comida_id' =>'2'])->count();
      $arrayPeticiones[$dias[$i]]['comida'] = $comidas;
      $arrayPeticiones[$dias[$i]]['cena'] = $cenas;
    }
```

Esto es el json que me devuelve en arrayFechas y donde me da el error Unexpected number

```
"{"2019-12-25":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-26":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-27":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-28":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-29":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-30":{"comida":2,"cena":0},"2019-12-31":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-01":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-02":{"comida":2,"cena":2},"2020-01-03":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-04":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-05":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-06":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-07":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-08":{"comida":1,"cena":0},"2020-01-09":{"comida":0,"cena":1},"2020-01-10":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-11":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-12":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-13":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-14":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-15":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-16":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-17":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-18":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-19":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-20":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-21":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-22":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-23":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-24":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-25":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-26":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-27":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-28":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-29":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-30":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-31":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-01":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-02":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-03":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-04":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-05":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-06":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-07":{"comida":0,"cena":0}}";
```

Comment: ese Json es correcto. Lo que te esta pasando es que asignas a arrayFechas una cadena json. quizas se solucione quitando las comillas, algo como `var arrayFechas= <?php echo json_encode($arrayPeticiones) ?>;` ya que parece mas bien cosa de javascript. De todas formas, donde te da el error? en la misma linea del var  arrayFechas??? Mas que nada porque el json esta roto por las " iniciales y finales

Comment: el error me lo da en la linea de var arrayFechas que me imprime el json que he puesto al final de mi pregunta y me pone SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: ok, te he añadido respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ese Json es correcto. Lo que te esta pasando es que asignas a arrayFechas una cadena json.

cuando haces:

```
var arrayFechas= "<?php echo json_encode($arrayPeticiones) ?>";
```

las " iniciales abren una cadena, y el json_encode las abre tambien para su cadena. Esto te queda incorrecto, y te da el error.

quita las comillas en la asignacion:

```
var arrayFechas= <?php echo json_encode($arrayPeticiones) ?>;
```

y ahora si, tu codigo quedaria cuando se ejecute como:

```
var arrayFechas ={"2019-12-25":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-26":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-27":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-28":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-29":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2019-12-30":{"comida":2,"cena":0},"2019-12-31":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-01":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-02":{"comida":2,"cena":2},"2020-01-03":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-04":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-05":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-06":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-07":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-08":{"comida":1,"cena":0},"2020-01-09":{"comida":0,"cena":1},"2020-01-10":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-11":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-12":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-13":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-14":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-15":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-16":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-17":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-18":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-19":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-20":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-21":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-22":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-23":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-24":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-25":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-26":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-27":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-28":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-29":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-30":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-01-31":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-01":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-02":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-03":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-04":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-05":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-06":{"comida":0,"cena":0},"2020-02-07":{"comida":0,"cena":0}};
```

lo cual es correcto

Answer (score 0):

Es que viendo tu código yo diría que la definición de la array multidimensional es errónea, por eso te está fallando.

Prueba modificando la forma de crear la array multidimensional haciéndolo de este modo y vuelve a pasar el json_encode.

```
$arrayPeticiones = array(
    array('2020-01-15', '0'),
    array('2020-01-15', '1')
);
```

EDITO:

Para poner los valores que correspondan, captura los valores y luego los asignas al array de este modo:

```
$valorComidas = getValorComidas();
$valorCenas = getValorComidas();

$arrayPeticiones = array(
    array('2020-01-15', $valorComidas),
    array('2020-01-15', $valorCenas)
);
```

Comment: en ese caso en el $arrayPeticiones['2020-01-15'][0] = 0 pero puede ser que que valga 4 o más. No es en la posicion 0 es 0 y en el 1 es 1

Comment: Claro, no era lo que indicas? En la posición 0, poner el valor '0'

Comment: me refiero que alomejor en el $arrayPeticiones['2020-01-15'][0] = 4 y en el $arrayPeticiones['2020-01-15'][1] = 0 , esto es en el 0 recupero las comidas que hay ese día y en el 1 recupero las cenas de ese día

Comment: Entonces guarda los valores de las comidas y cenas en una variable y luego las asignas al array. He editado mi respuesta con lo que comento...

Comment: Pero en tu respuesta como diferencio entre los array para saber cual pertenece a comidas y cual a cenas.